# Debug in PowerShell 7 (Windows Terminal) instead of debug console with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: powershell, visual-studio, debugging, terminal, command-line

I have been scouring the internet without finding an answer to my questions, so I'll try my luck here. Could for some be a very stupid question but they need to be asked and answered too.

Is it possible to debug or "star without debugging" console apps from Visual Studio 2022 in PowerShell 7 (default profile in Windows Terminal) instead of the debugging console.

Windows Terminal is launched as it is my default terminal app, but the C# code is run in the debug console instead of PowerShell 7, which I have set as my default profile.

Any help with that?

I have set Terminal as my default terminal app and PowerShell 7 as my default shell profile.
I expect my C# code to launch and debug in PowerShell 7 instead of debugging console.